# Arduino 1.6.9 and later c++ support

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm going to create an app for Arduino. Currently I installed 1.6.9 version. I'd like to use C++. I know that exceptions and dynamic allocation are not supported, but where can I get exact list of which C++ features are not supported?
There are some info in the internet, but some is quite old, other is too general...

Thanks in advance,
A

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation of Atmel for AVR Libc](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/FAQ_1faq_cplusplus.html) is the following answer to the question *Can I use C++ on the AVR?*:

> Basically yes, C++ is supported (assuming your compiler has been configured and compiled to support it, of course). Source files ending in .cc, .cpp or .C will automatically cause the compiler frontend to invoke the C++ compiler. Alternatively, the C++ compiler could be explicitly called by the name avr-c++.
> However, there's currently no support for libstdc++, the standard support library needed for a complete C++ implementation. This imposes a number of restrictions on the C++ programs that can be compiled. Among them are:
>
> - Obviously, none of the C++ related standard functions, classes, and template classes are available.
> - The operators new and delete are not implemented, attempting to use them will cause the linker to complain about undefined external references. (This could perhaps be fixed.)
> - Some of the supplied include files are not C++ safe, i. e. they need to be wrapped into
>   `extern"C" { . . . }` 
>   (This could certainly be fixed, too.)
> - Exceptions are not supported. Since exceptions are enabled by default in the C++ frontend, they explicitly need to be turned off using -fno-exceptions in the compiler options. Failing this, the linker will complain about an undefined external reference to __gxx_personality_sj0.
>
> Constructors and destructors are supported though, including global ones.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I saw that information. How old is the text? Not sure it is relevant now. For example "this could certainly be fixed, too" from the text says that C++ support could be expanded. That's why I asked about actual information for the current time. Probably I just need to run some tests if there are not a good info resource.

Comment: Right, there is no specific version mentioned to which these answers apply. The latest reference to C++ is one entry in the NEWS file within the source repository stating: "Mention Jörn's recent changes to make avr-libc more C++ aware." This change is from 2014. To get more details, you might have a look in the [subversion repository](http://svn.savannah.nongnu.org/viewvc/trunk/avr-libc/?root=avr-libc.).

Comment: BTW, do you know whether there are some test suite that check C++ workability in avr-gcc?